# Angular navigate content without change component

Tags: javascript, angular, router

I have 2 components: componentA and componentB
When I click a button in componentA, this will navigate to componentB, but componentA and componentB have same filter and left sidebar, the only thing different is content

```
ComponentA.html

    <app-new-post></app-new-post>
    <app-filter-forum></app-filter-forum>
    <app-view-topic [topicData]="viewContent"
    (showSubTopic)="onShowSubTopic($event)"></app-view-topic>
```

```
ComponentA.ts
onShowSubTopic() {
   this.router.navigate([ComponentB])
}
```

```
ComponentB.html

    <app-new-post></app-new-post>
    <app-filter-forum></app-filter-forum>
    <app-sub-topic></app-sub-topic>
```

Is there any ways to use 1 component to display both of them?

Comment: Can you please provide some extra explanation by giving proper example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution will definitely work, but ideally, you should be using the Angular router.  Which is what I think you're trying to achieve here.

Here would are the changes you would need to implement:

```
someRootComponent.html
    <app-new-post></app-new-post>
    <app-filter-forum></app-filter-forum>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

At this point you can get rid of ComponentA and componentB.  Your routes would look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'view-topic', component: ViewTopicComponent },
  { path: 'sub-topic', component: SubTopicComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },  // Wildcard route for a 404 page
];
```

The eventual problem you'll run into is managing state.  There are many approaches to handling this.  If you wanted to support deep linking, then I suggest doing this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'view-topic/:topicId', component: ViewTopicComponent },
  { path: 'sub-topic/:subTopicId', component: SubTopicComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },  // Wildcard route for a 404 page
];
```

This is how you would link to a topic:

```
  <a [routerLink]="['/view-topic', topic.id]">
```

The Angular router docs are excellent, it's available here:
[Angular Router Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngIf to check to show the different dom

```
ComponentA.html
    <app-new-post></app-new-post>
    <app-filter-forum></app-filter-forum>
    <app-view-topic [topicData]="viewContent" *ngIf="!showBComponent"
        (showSubTopic)="onShowSubTopic($event)"></app-view-topic>
    <app-sub-topic *ngIf="showBComponent "></app-sub-topic>

ComponentA.ts
    let showBComponent: boolean = false;
    onShowSubTopic(e: any): void {
        this.showBComponent = true;
    }
```